# The old version of Google Translate

Tags: google-translate, machine-translation

I need the old version of Google Translate (the statistical model, the version before 2016) for my research,
I was wondering if there any way to access the old version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See the update below

##### Original answer

**Yes**, as of 2020, Google Translate statistical machine translation still available as **phrase-based** machine translation.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text

> **Using the model parameter**
>
> You can specify which model to use for translation by using the `model` query parameter. Specify `base` to use the PBMT model, and `nmt` to use the NMT model. If you specify the NMT model in your request and the requested language translation pair is not supported for the NMT model, then the PBMT model is used.

There are similar options for the Microsoft API and the undocumented Google APIs.

My guess is that there are no statistical systems available for newly added language pairs - a major advantage of massive multilingual models is not having to train or deploy separate systems for the long tail.

##### Update

**No**, Google ended statistical machine translation in **August 2021**.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/release-notes#August_02_2021

> ###### August 02, 2021
>
> changed
> Removed the Phrase-Based Machine Translation (PBMT) model. For requests that specify the PBMT model, Cloud Translation uses the Neural Machine Translation (NMT) model instead.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#model

> **Note:** Translation previously offered a Phrase-Based Machine Translation (PBMT) model (also known as the `base` model). If you specify that model for translations, Translation uses the NMT model instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check [Google Translate in the Web Archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151024015132/https://translate.google.com/)

Comment: Hi, Its just an snapshot of the site, I want to use the old translator to translate some sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is running somewhere. The statistical system is a complicated pipeline that is expensive to run and difficult to maintain.

You can try contacting someone from Google Research who works on MT (just have a look at papers on arXiv, the authors have contact emails there) if they can run it for you.

Alternatively, you can build your own [Moses system](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder), it is an open-source implementation of statistical MT, so the results should be similar to what was Google Translate (judging from the [WMT competitions](http://www.statmt.org/wmt15/) results before 2016).